# Sticky.js appears to not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, sticky

I am currently trying to get [sticky.js](https://github.com/dfcreative/sticky) to work on my web page... on the navbar - and unfortunately it does not work! I have tried two different plugins, but neither seem to work!

For those who do not know, the thought behind the plugin is that it's supposed to make a certain html element get 'stuck' to the screen once you scroll down... I've been inspired by the codeanywhere.com navigation menu, and want to do something similar!

Would someone mind taking a look at my [website page](http://pixelcrescent.com/) and troubleshooting as to why my my [current (Same as sticky.js link from above)](https://github.com/dfcreative/sticky) sticky plugin does not work?

I am absolutely novice when it comes to javascript. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try Below Code...

Changes:

1) Included Jquery CDN in head section

2) Included revised Style in head (alter as per your requirements)

3) Revised javascript at the end.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Home &#126; Pixel Crescent</title>
    <base href="http://pixelcrescent.com/" />
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport">
    <link href="assets/templates/css/kube.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="assets/templates/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


    <style>
        .stick-nav-left {
            position:fixed;
            top:0px;
            z-index:99;
        }

        .stick-nav-right {
            position:fixed;
            top:0px;
            right:0px;
            z-index:99;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="background: white;">
    <div class="units-row wide-pic">
        <div class="units-row">
        <div id="header" class="unit-80 unit-centered">
                <nav class="navbar navbar-left" id="navbar-left">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a class="btn-space" href="http://pixelcrescent.com">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a class="btn-space" href="http://pixelcrescent.com/products">Products</a></li>
                        <li><a class="btn-space" href="http://pixelcrescent.com/docs">Documentation</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
                <nav class="navbar navbar-right" id="navbar-right">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a class="btn-space" href="#">Sign up</a></li>
                            <li><a class="btn btn-blue" href="#">Sign in</a></li>
                        </ul>
                </nav>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="units-row" style="margin-top: 150px">
            <div class="unit-60 unit-centered" id="logotext">
                <h1>
                    Pixel Crescent
                </h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="text-align: center;" class="units-row upper-shadow">
        <div class="unit-centered unit-90">
            <hgroup>
            <h1>
                Home
            </h1>
            <h1 class="subheading">
                Make an Impact.
            </h1>
            </hgroup>
            <p class="lead">
                All of our products are developed with usability and satisfaction in mind. Don't settle for substandard work; build satisfaction, gain loyalty, and increase communication with your customers through our services. 
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="units-row end">

        <div class="unit-90 unit-centered">
            <h1>High Quality products at low budget prices</h1>

<p>Are you looking for ways to cut down on development time, increase productivity and keep your clients happy?<br />
We've got you covered!</p>

<div class="units-row">
<div class="unit-33 shadow-box">
    <hgroup>
        <h2>
            Aligned
        </h2>
        <h2 class="subheading">
            "Under Construction" Page
        </h2>
    </hgroup>
            <p>
            <b>Features</b><br>
            No-database 'Email Subscribe' form<br>
            Logo<br>
            Responsive<br>
            Multi-Colors<br>
        </p>
        <hr>
        <strong>Get it for</strong>
        <h4>
            $0
        </h4>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-blue">
            Download now!
        </a>
        <a href="docs/aligned/" class="btn">
            Documentation
        </a>
</div>
<div class="unit-33 shadow-box">
    <hgroup>
        <h2>
            ManageMeat
        </h2>
        <h2 class="subheading">
            Account Management System
        </h2>
    </hgroup>
            <p>
            <b>Features</b><br>
            Admin Panel<br>
            MySQL Database<br>
            Customizeable Account Info<br>
            Built for security<br>
        </p>
        <hr>
        <strong>Get it for</strong>
        <h4>
            $5
        </h4>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-blue">
            Purchase
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="btn">
            Documentation
        </a>
</div>
<div class="unit-33 shadow-box">
    <hgroup>
        <h2>
            Order a Website
        </h2>
        <h2 class="subheading">
            Professionally Designed & Affordable.
        </h2>
    </hgroup>
            <p>
            <b>Features</b><br>
            We fit every budget<br>
            Custom Design<br>
            Self Customizable<br>
            Installation of other software upon request<br> 
        </p>
        <hr>
        <strong>Price</strong>
        <h4>
            Catered to your need
        </h4>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-blue">
            Free Quote
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="btn">
            Why Pixel Crescent?
        </a>
/div>
</div>
        </div>

    </div>
    </div>
    <!--- Footer --->
    <footer>
        <div>
        <h5>
            Copyright Pixel Crescent &copy; 2013-2014
        </h5>
    </div>
    </footer>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
   var nav_lft = $("#navbar-left");
   var pos1 = nav_lft.position();  

   var nav_rgt = $("#navbar-right");
   var pos2 = nav_rgt.position();  

   $(window).scroll(function() {
       var windowpos = $(window).scrollTop();

    //-----Left navbar
       if (windowpos >= pos1.top)
           nav_lft.addClass("stick-nav-left");
       else
           nav_lft.removeClass("stick-nav-left");  

    //-----Right navbar
       if (windowpos >= pos2.top)
           nav_rgt.addClass("stick-nav-right");
       else
           nav_rgt.removeClass("stick-nav-right");
  });

});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! Having some troubles with the right navbar, so I've decided to put this on hold for now... regardless, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

1) Add id to your navbar

2) Use below Javascript :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var s = $("#navbar");
   var pos = s.position();  

   $(window).scroll(function() {
       var windowpos = $(window).scrollTop();

       if (windowpos >= pos.top) {
           s.addClass("stick");
       } else {
           s.removeClass("stick");  
       }
  });

});
```

3) And below CSS class

```
.stick{
   position:fixed;
   top:0px;
   z-index:99;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't appear to work - can you check the code that I've used, it's on the updated page?